# Change Text Color in MFC C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I want to change the color of the LVITEM?
m_szList is the CListCtrl.

```
LVITEM lvItem;

    lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.iItem = 0;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.pszText = _T("Sandra");
    m_szList.InsertItem(&lvItem);
    m_szList.SetTextColor(RGB(255, 78, 12));

    lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.iItem = 1;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.pszText = _T("Roger");
    m_szList.InsertItem(&lvItem);
```

This code can change the both color of sandra and roger.
But i just want to change the color of sandra to red.
And roger to default(black).

Comment: As you have noticed, SetTextColor set the text color for entire list ... so, I guess you should use some extended listcontrol: https://www.google.ro/search?q=CListCtrlExt+codeproject&spell=1&sa=X&ei=d5tZVZ7AL6WcygOBioCgBw&ved=0CBkQvwUoAA&biw=1152&bih=634

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Custom-draw list control for this job.

You make the control custom draw by responding to the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` message. This is notification message that's sent *from* the control. Using MFC, your function header will look something like this:

```
void CCustomLvView::OnNMCustomdraw(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
```

To add this handler, you normally use the Properties list for the CListCtrl (or CListView), something like this:

[image]

That'll create a handler something like this:

```
void CCustomLV2View::OnNMCustomdraw(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult) {
    LPNMCUSTOMDRAW pNMCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);

    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
}
```

[If memory serves, it also has a comment or two.]

You'll need to add a little code to that to change the text color, something on this order:

```
void CCustomLV2View::OnNMCustomdraw(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult) {
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW pNMCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);

    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;

    switch (pNMCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage) {
        // this tells the control, before any painting begins, that we 
        // want to be notified just before any item in the control is drawn.
        case CDDS_PREPAINT:
            *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
            break;

        // This will be called before an item is drawn.
        // We check what item is being drawn, and set the text color appropriately
        case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
            if (pNMCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec == 0)
                pNMCD->clrText = RGB(0, 0, 0);
            else
                pNMCD->clrText = RGB(255, 78, 12);
            break;
    }
}
```

As it is right now, this draws the text for the first item in black, and all subsequent items in your shade of red. The `if (pNMCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec == 0)` is what chooses the items, and (of course) the `pNMCD->clrText = RGB...` is what sets the text color.

Also note that I've made a fairly minor modification to the code it generates, so I have a `LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW` instead of a `LPNMCUSTOMDRAW`. This gives access to the ListView-specific fields passed to the custom-draw handler. Without that, we don't get access to some of (any of?) the fields we're using.

Comment: `pNMCD->clrTextBk` in case he wants a background color later too. +1

Comment: `CListCtrl::SetItemData` and `CListCtrl::GetItemData` can also be used to store the desired color and then retrieve it in this method.